# Select items from IEnumerable

Tags: c#

I am trying to find the date for which a file exists in folder and getting an errror while trying to use IEnumerable.

```
DateTime testDate = ("2021-05-09");
DateTime snapshotDate  = Enumerable.Range(0, 30)
    .Select(i => DateTime.Parse(@testDate).AddDays(-i))
    .FirstOrDefault(s => EXISTS(string.Format(@"/users/{0:yyyy/MM}/testfile_{0:yyyyMMdd}.txt", DateTime.Parse(@testDate).AddDays(-s))));
```

Please let me what i am missing here

Comment: maybe the most important part of this questions is:   WHAT IS THE ERROR??

Comment: What is `EXISTS`?

Comment: Operator '-' cannot be applied to operand of type 'DateTime'
Description:
C# compiler reported that this expression is not valid C#.

DateTime.Parse(@testDate).AddDays( ### -s))));

Comment: @GuruStron, I am trying to check if the file path exists for that date or not, if file exists, give me date. Apologies if my question is not clear. Basicaly I have a folder with file generated wtih format f as filename_yyyMMDS, i need to find the first date where these files exists. for eg. say   I am checking for date, 2021-05-09, but files present in that folder are from 2021-05-03 only then i need to get the 2021-05-03 as output

Comment: @novice8989 `s` is a date, you can't negate a date. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either remove `Select`, or format the date:

```cs
string testDate = "2021-05-09";
DateTime snapshotDate  = Enumerable.Range(0, 30)
    .Select(i => DateTime.Parse(@testDate).AddDays(-i))
    .FirstOrDefault(s => EXISTS(
        string.Format(@"/users/{0:yyyy/MM}/testfile_{0:yyyyMMdd}.txt", s))); // here
```

Note that since `DateTime` is struct `FirstOrDefault` will return default value - `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` and not a `null`.

Comment: Thank you , how will the s variable value will be decremented? if I don't apply the .addays(-i)     as I need to make sure that file exists for that date and then only capture that date value. I might be missing something here

Comment: @novice8989 you decrement it in the `Select`, you don't need to decrement it again. I recommend you to go trough some LINQ tutorial.

Comment: Thank you , I got it now.  "s" has the date decremented value which is passed to the exists condition. Hope I understand it right?

Comment: Yeah, I need to go thru tutorial , time crunch but thats not aan excuse Thank you for patiently explaining

Comment: @novice8989 yes. But don't take it for granted - test it yourself =)